# Whenever I run turtle module, my computer automatically logs off

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

As the title says, whenever I run turtle module and try to use Turtle by import turtle and bob = turtle.Turtle(), my computer logs off and the internet connections is even lost.

I tried to find a similar problem on internet, but I couldn't find it. Below is what I got on terminal.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from turtle import Turtle
>>> t1 = Turtle()
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.461 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.462 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.462 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.463 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.463 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.463 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.463 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.463 python[10363:4080288] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-09-11 15:26:36.472 python[10363:4080288] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2019-09-11 15:26:36.472 python[10363:4080288] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop

[Restored Sep 11, 2019 at 3:26:48 PM]
```

Comment: I think I saw similar problem on Stackoverflow - and problem was only on Mac. I think there was no solutin for this but I don't use Mac to say something more.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217405/turtle-graphics-not-responding